# What the 'run bot runner session on control room' option's for?

Tags: bots, rpa, automationanywhere

This option is available when you schedule a task from the control room.

[image: options image]

But I don't undestand what is does can someone explain me this ?

Answer (score 0):

Run bot runner session on control room is used to run a bot in a device that in a **locked state**.

Typically, when a Bot is deployed from the Automation Anywhere Enterprise Control Room to any Bot Runner, the Bot will attempt to auto-login into the Bot Runner (if the Bot Runner is locked or logged off).

**What is RDP Based Bot Deployment?**
When the Bot is deployed from Control Room onto the Bot Runner, the Control Room will take the Bot Runner session via RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) and will execute the Bot.

**Key features and benefits of this approach**
The Bot runs in the Bot Runner’s RDP session in the Control Room in the background; no window is visible on the Control Room.
Auto-Login issues are mitigated as auto-login is not attempted; auto-login will ONLY be attempted if RDP fails in the first place.
As Bot Runner machine is not auto-logged in; the security issues related to ‘live monitor’ scenarios are mitigated.

Answer (score 0):

Select Run Bot Runner Session on Control Room.
This allows the Control Room to use the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) of the Bot Runner machine to run a scheduled task if it is in locked or logged-off state. This method is recommended when bots are deployed on virtual machines and terminal servers.
You can also choose to set the RDP screen resolution using the Set bot runner screen resolution option so that the resolution of the Bot Creator and Bot Runner screens match.

For more details, see Guidelines for RDP-based bot deployment.
https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/enterprise/topics/control-room/bots/my-bots/rdp-based-approach-to-bot-deployment.html

Reference: https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/enterprise/topics/control-room/bots/my-bots/run-a-bot.html